# Maven not compiling with dependencies from parent pom

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have following parent pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <description>example-parent</description>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-sling-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
                    <artifactId>htl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.6</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <version>4.1.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
                <artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.5.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.3</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0.1398</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.aem</groupId>
            <artifactId>uber-jar</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.0</version>
            <classifier>apis</classifier>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.sling.models.api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.acs</groupId>
            <artifactId>acs-aem-commons-content</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0</version>
            <classifier>min</classifier>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <type>zip</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-atinject_1.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.sling.jcr.jcr-wrapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>biz.aQute</groupId>
            <artifactId>bndlib</artifactId>
            <version>1.50.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.day.commons.osgi.wrapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.day.commons.osgi.wrapper.commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.018</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.cq</groupId>
            <artifactId>core.wcm.components.all</artifactId>
            <type>zip</type>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.cq</groupId>
            <artifactId>core.wcm.components.extension</artifactId>
            <type>zip</type>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.22</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit-addons</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-addons</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>osgi.annotation</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.service.metatype.annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.service.component.annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.service.component</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

and following child pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>example-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>example-core</artifactId>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <name>example.core</name>
    <description>example-core</description>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-sling-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Import-Package>javax.inject;version=0.0.0,*</Import-Package>
                        <Sling-Model-Packages>
                            com.example
                        </Sling-Model-Packages>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

If I'm compiling something with the OSGi annotation, e.g.

```
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Reference;

@Designate(ocd=CopyrightChecksScheduledTask.Config.class)
@Component(service=Runnable.class)
public class CopyrightChecksScheduledTask implements Runnable {

    private String myParameter;

    @Reference
    private ResourceResolverFactory resolverFactory;

    @Override
    public void run() {
    }

    @Activate
    protected void activate(final Config config) {
        myParameter = config.myParameter();
    }

}
```

I get following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) on project example.core: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /core/src/main/java/com/example/core/schedulers/CopyrightChecksScheduledTask.java:[55,9] annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration
[ERROR] /core/src/main/java/com/example/core/schedulers/CleanupScheduledTask.java:[25,9] annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration
```

If I move following dependencies to dependencyManagement in the parent pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>osgi.annotation</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.service.metatype.annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.service.component.annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.service.component</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

and add the same dependencies to the child pom.xml it compiles without any error.

[How to inherit dependency from a parent pom to a child pom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882221/how-to-inherit-dependency-from-a-parent-pom-to-a-child-pom):

> You should declare dependencies you want to inherit under a
>   `<dependencies>` section to achieve this. `<dependencyManagement>` is used
>   for definitions that must be referenced later, whenever needed, within
>   the `<dependencies>` of a particular child to become effective.

Why does this not work in my setup?

Answer (score 2):

It's actually not about your dependencies, but the annotation usage. Annotation `public @interface Reference` has `@Target(value=METHOD)`, so it's for annotating methods, not fields.

Comment: This makes it even weirder, how come it builds one way but not the other? Also all tutorials using OSGi R7 examples use the annotation the same way?  

Explanation here: http://blogs.adobe.com/experiencedelivers/experience-management/osgi/using-osgi-r7-annotations-aem/

Source here: https://github.com/heervisscher/htl-examples/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/adobe/examples/htl/core/service/impl/MySimpleServiceImpl.java

Comment: I'm not sure if it compiles at all. If so, it can be about dependencies versions. I would say it's quite unusual to do such a change in the API, but sometimes it happens. You can compare different versions of this lib to see how it changes.

Comment: Indeed it compiles without a problem, as said only if the dependencies are directly in the childs.pom and not on the parent.pom, which is super odd to me :-/